# I need to transform every element in a list of a column to a new column in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in Python that look likethe following:

```
   Name   Hobbies
0  Paul   ["Watch_NBA", "Play_PS4"]
1  Jeff   ["Play_hockey", "Read", "Play_PS4"]
2  Kyle   ["Sleep", "Watch_NBA"]
```

I need to transform every element of the list in a new column and assign the value of 0 or 1 if it appears in the original list. The result show be the following:

```
   Name   Watch_NBA  Play_PS4 Play_hockey Read Sleep
0  Paul       1          1        0        0     0
1  Jeff       0          1        1        1     0
2  Kyle       1          0        0        0     1
```

Someone knows how i could to this. Take in mind that i will use a lot of Hobbies in the column, so it show be a little automated and not hardcoded. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

[`get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) is good but `sklearn's` [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) has better performance:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
a = mlb.fit_transform(df["Hobbies"])
df_expanded = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index)

# merge them using the following:
df_merged = df.merge(df_expanded, left_index=True, right_index=True)

print(df_merged)

index   Name    Hobbies                         Play_PS4    Play_hockey Read    Sleep   Watch_NBA
0       Paul    [Watch_NBA, Play_PS4]           1           0           0       0       1
1       Jeff    [Play_hockey, Read, Play_PS4]   1           1           1       0       0
2       Kyle    [Sleep, Watch_NBA]              0           0           0       1       1
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the `get_dummies()` method. Documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html).

For your example:

```
names = df.Name
df = pd.get_dummies(df.Hobbies.apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0)
df.insert(0, 'Name', names)

#output:
   Name  Play_PS4  Play_hockey  Read  Sleep  Watch_NBA
0  Paul         1            0     0      0          1
1  Jeff         1            1     1      0          0
2  Kyle         0            0     0      1          1
```

Comment: An example of how to use this method to solve OP's question would be a much more fitting answer

Comment: added for his example :)

Answer (score 1):

```
In [86]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[86]: 
   Name              Hobbies
0  Paul           [NBA, PS4]
1  Jeff  [Hockey, Read, PS4]
2  Kyle         [Sleep, NBA]

In [87]: df['dummy'] = 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [88]: df.explode("Hobbies").pivot(index='Name', columns='Hobbies', values='dummy').fillna(value=0)                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[88]: 
Hobbies  Hockey  NBA  PS4  Read  Sleep
Name                                  
Jeff        1.0  0.0  1.0   1.0    0.0
Kyle        0.0  1.0  0.0   0.0    1.0
Paul        0.0  1.0  1.0   0.0    0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
n = df['Name']
df = df['Hobbies'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([1] * len(x), index=x)).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
df.insert(0, 'Name', n)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   Name  Watch_NBA  Play_PS4  Play_hockey  Read  Sleep
0  Paul          1         1            0     0      0
1  Jeff          0         1            1     1      0
2  Kyle          1         0            0     0      1
```